# angularjs : ng-click event is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to append li element using jquery.the "li" element is appended successfully howerver ng-click event is not working. please help.

below is my code.

```
$(".language-list").append("<li><span ng-click='selectOperator(op)'><label for=checkbox" + $scope.allOperators[op].operator_id +   " class=labeloperator" + ">" + $scope.allOperators[op].operator_name + "</label></div></span></li>");
```

Comment: where do you run this line? in directive? if yes, $compile it first

Comment: no not in directive. i am running it on inside controller.

Comment: I'm sure you know by now that this is not really the right way to write Angular. You should always favour templates over direct DOM manipulation. This looks more like a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compile the dynamic HTML to do the work.

```
$(".language-list")
  .append(
        $compile(
           "<li><span ng-click='selectOperator(op)'><label for=checkbox" + 
            $scope.allOperators[op].operator_id +   " class=labeloperator" + ">" +
            $scope.allOperators[op].operator_name + "</label></div></span></li>")
 )($scope);
```

[For more Information about $compile service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Answer (score 5):

On append you need compile the element.

**It not good practice to do that in controller. Use directive for any DOM selection/manipulation.**

Anyways here is example:

```
var elmnt = angular.element(/* ... */);


elmnt.append(
           $compile(
           "<li><span ng-click='selectOperator(op)'><label for=checkbox" + $scope.allOperators[op].operator_id +   " class=labeloperator" + ">" + $scope.allOperators[op].operator_name + "</label></div></span></li>"
               )($scope));
```